# Appgyver - Unable to load resource's data model - dreamfactory API

Tags: json, appgyver

I have [this json feed](http://dreamfactory-inventivemedia.rhcloud.com/rest/vlaamse_vinyl/taggen?app_name=vlaamse_vinyl).

I am unable to load this into Appgyver
I have set the following required settings:
- parameter app_name with the correct value
- added the reuired header X-DREAMFACTORY-APPLICATION-NAME

I always get the `Oops, Unable to load resource's data model.` error

Anyone who has a clue?

Comment: The feed returns this for us: `{"error":[{"context":null,"message":"There is no valid session for the current request.","code":401}]}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with AppGyver, but I know it's been used with DreamFactory successfully by others. You have not provided enough information, but I will attempt to give you troubleshooting steps from the DreamFactory side.

First, are you definitely authenticating and passing a valid `X-DreamFactory-Session-Token` header? I can tell that you don't have guest access enabled (to make calls without authentication) because when I navigate to [your link](http://dreamfactory-inventivemedia.rhcloud.com/rest/vlaamse_vinyl/taggen?app_name=vlaamse_vinyl) I receive a 401 with "There is no valid session for the current request."

Second, what is the call you're making from AppGyver? Is it a GET to simply list resources of a DB called `vlaamse_vinyl`, or what?

Finally, if you are passing `X-DreamFactory-Application-Name` in addition to the URI parameter `?app_name=vlaamse_vinyl` this is redundant. Perhaps that is preventing your call from succeeding.